# Trying to add image from database but onload not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am trying to draw an image on to a canvas in a Cordova application. I believe I have the Base64 image correct as I have used several methods to encode it and they all seem to return the same data string.

The code below seems to run fine, passing the data into the img.src but the onload does not fire. I have searched probably 50+ questions to see how to do this and they all seem to use the way I am doing it but onload is not firing.

picsSelectAll() is attached to a button in my HTML that is pressed after the page loads, I have also tried to call it in on Deviceready, but it still does the same thing.

Any suggestions on different things to try would be massively appreciated, I have been on this for days now and just can't get past it.

```
function picsPhotodataSelectHandler(tx, results){

    console.log("Photodata had Results: "+results.rows.length);
        // Handle the results
        for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {
            var row = results.rows.item(i);

            var newImage = new Object();
            newImage.picid = row['id'];
            newImage.encodedtext = row['img_uri'];
            canvasData.push(newImage);
        }
        showImagesFromDB();
    }

function picsSelectAll(){ 

    db.transaction(
        function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT id, img_uri from insc_snags WHERE id=81;", [], picsPhotodataSelectHandler, transaction_error);
        }
    );  
}

function drawImageOnCanvas(data, canvas) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        };


        img.src = data;
    }

function getCanvasDataByID(ID){
        for (var i=0; i<canvasData.length;i++){
            if (canvasData[i].picid == ID) {
                return canvasData[i].encodedtext;           
            }
        }
        return '';  
    }

function showImagesFromDB() {
        var container = document.getElementById('img-container')
        container.innerHTML='';

        for (var i=0; i<canvasData.length; i++){
            var canvasImg = document.createElement("canvas");
            var imgID = canvasData[i].picid;

            canvasImg.setAttribute("id", 'cx'+imgID);
            //canvasImg.setAttribute("title", data[i].desc);

            drawImageOnCanvas(getCanvasDataByID(imgID), canvasImg);

            container.appendChild(canvasImg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add `container.appendChild(canvasImg);` before `drawImageOnCanvas(getCanvasDataByID(imgID), canvasImg);`. It might do the trick, but not 100% sure.

Comment: Tried that but unfortunately it didn't work. The canvas still draws but the image is still blank and the onload still does  not fire

Comment: must have been something else on the page that was causing the issue, started with a clean page and it worked